# Confusion about the space of functions on $D(x) \cup D(y)$ in $\mathbb A^2_k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, proof-explanation

The following questions concern notes from Vakil's notes on Algebraic Geometry (page 140):

---

How is it clear that the rational functions with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and only powers of $y$ in the denominator, are the polynomials? The function $1/y$ is not even in $D(x)$.

Also, if this is the case, then how is $\Gamma(U, \mathcal O_{\mathbb A^2_k})=k[x,y]$?

> [image]

Comment: If $g/x^n=h/y^m$ with $g$ coprime to $x$ and $h$ coprime to $y$ then $gy^m=hx^n$, so $y^m\mid x^n$ which is only possible if $m=0$, similar for $n$.

Comment: In integral schemes we can naturally identify every ring of sections $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ with a subring of the function field. Under this identification $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)=\Gamma(U_1,\mathcal{O}_X)\cap \Gamma(U_2,\mathcal{O}_X)$ if $U=U_1\cup U_2$. If we apply this to $U_1=D(x),U_2=D(y)$ we see that $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)=A_x\cap A_y$ and by the reasoning above this intersection is just $A$

Comment: @leoli1 Why does he make that statement: $\textit{"Clearly those rational functions with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and also with only powers of $y$ in the denominator, are the polynomials."}$ Isn't this false since $1/y$ is not in $D(x)$?

Comment: Because that implies $A_x\cap A_y=A$, hence $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)=A$

Comment: Can you write $1/y$ as a polynomial in $x,y$ divided by a power of $x$?

Comment: @leoli1 No you cannot. But I think we're getting ahead of my question. How is he deriving the highlighted statement from the previous sentence? How is he using the sentence "we are looking for functions on $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ that agree on $D(x) \cap D(y) = D(xy)$"?

Comment: That is the justification for $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)=A_x\cap A_y$

Comment: @leoli1 But you're jumping ahead. He uses the previous two sentences to conclude $A_x \cap A_y = A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $s$ is a rational function with only powers of $x$ in the denominator. So $s = g/x^m$ and we can assume $x \not\mid g$. Now suppose $s$ also has only powers of $y$ in the denominator. So $s = h/y^n$ and again we may as well assume $y \not\mid h$.

So $gy^n = hx^m$ and since $x \not\mid g$ we know $x^m \mid y^n$. Thus $m = 0$. Likewise $n = 0$. Therefore $s = g = h$ is a polynomial.

Comment: How does he go from "we are looking for functions on $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ that agree on $D(x) \cap D(y) = D(xy)$" to "Clearly those rational functions with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and also with only powers of $y$ in the denominator, are the polynomials." ?

Comment: "Agree on $D(xy)$" means the functions are restrictions of functions on $\Gamma(D(xy)) = A_{xy} \subset k(x,y)$. A function on $D(x)$ is an element of $A_x$, a function on $D(y)$ is an element of $A_y$. So we are looking for functions in $A_{xy}$ which are in both $A_x$ and in $A_y$.

Comment: Isn't the statement $\textit{"Clearly those rational functions with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and also with only powers of $y$ in the denominator, are the polynomials."}$ false since $1/x$ is a rational function with only powers of $x$ in the denominator but $1/x$ is not a function on $D(y)$?

Comment: Is $1/x$ a "rational function with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, *and also with only powers of $y$ in the denominator*"?

Comment: Yes, $\frac{1}{x}= \frac{1}{x^1 y^0}$. Maybe I'm confused with the wording?

Comment: $1/x$ does not have only powers of $y$ in the denominator.

Comment: The statment "rational functions with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and also with only powers of $y$ in the denominator" to me sounds like $\left\{\frac{f(x,y)}{x^m} \mid f(x,y) \in k[x,y], m \in \mathbb Z \right\} \cup \left\{\frac{g(x,y)}{y^n} \mid g(x,y) \in k[x,y], n \in \mathbb Z \right\}$. Is this not the case?

Comment: @AlJebr no that is not the case. We are looking at a single element of $\Gamma(U)$ that is going to be a single rational function which is simultaneously a function on $D(x)$ and a function on $D(y)$. That is a single function which simultaneously has only powers of $x$ in the denominator (so is a function on $D(x)$) and at the same time has only powers of $y$ in the denominator as well (so is a function on $D(y)$). That is, the intersection $A_x \cap A_y$.