# Finding the functions on the plane minus the origin by gluing the functions on distinguished open sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, sheaf-theory, schemes

I'm trying to understand the following example from [Vakil's text](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf):

> [image]

I believe he wants to apply the gluability axiom of the structure sheaf, so he is looking for $f_1\in A_x$ and $f_2\in A_y$ such that $Res_{D(x),D(xy)}f_1=Res_{D(y),D(xy)} f_2$, so  writes:

> So we are looking for functions on $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ that agree on $D(x)\cap D(y)=D(xy)$

But what does he mean by "interpreting" in the statement below, and how is it related to the above?

> i.e, we are interpreting $A_x\cap A_y$ in $A_{xy}$ (or in $k(x,y)$)

Next, he writes:

> Clearly those rational functions
> with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and also with only powers of y in the
> denominator, are the polynomials. Translation: $A_x\cap A_y=A$

At this point I've completely lost the discussion thread. I guess this is related to my previous confusion. Why do we need/want to consider $A_x\cap A_y$? How are $D(x), D(y), D(x)\cap D(y)$ related to this?

What are the $f_1$ and $f_2$ that we wanted to find? Have we found them? And suppose that we've found them. Then the gluability axiom tells us that there is $f\in \mathscr O_{\mathbb A^2}(U)$ such that $Res_{U,U_i} f= f_i$. How does this imply the last claim quoted below?

> Thus we conclude $\Gamma(U, \mathscr O_{\mathbb A^2} )\equiv k[x,y]$

Comment: This particular problem has been discussed to *death* on MSE and is likely a duplicate many times over. Have you explored any of the other questions on this site dealing with it? For instance, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980668/the-global-sections-of-the-affine-plane-with-the-origin-removed/3980681#3980681) or any of those listed in the sidebar under related questions?

Comment: @KReiser Now I have, but most of the previous questions use a different approach/setting (or at least the approach that looks different to me) and cause even more questions. The closest question is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984002/confusion-about-the-space-of-functions-on-dx-cup-dy-in-mathbb-a2-k?rq=1) but I still don't understand how elements of $A_x\cap A_y$ are related to what I called $f_1$ and $f_2$ and how the conclusion of the gluability axiom is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe he wants to apply the gluability axiom of the structure sheaf, so he is looking for $f_1\in A_x$ and $f_2\in A_y$ such that $Res_{D(x),D(xy)}f_1=Res_{D(y),D(xy)} f_2$, so  writes:
>
> > So we are looking for functions on $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ that agree on $D(x)\cap D(y)=D(xy)$

Yes, by the sheaf axioms, since $D(x)$ and $D(y)$ cover $D(x)\cup D(y)$ with intersection $D(x)\cap D(y)=D(xy)$, sections of $\mathcal{O}_X$ over $D(x)\cup D(y)$ are exactly the choice of an $f_1\in \mathcal{O}_X(D(x)) = A_x$ and $f_2\in \mathcal{O}_X(D(y))=A_y$ so that $f_1|_{D(xy)}=f_2|_{D(xy)}$ in $A_{xy}$.

> But what does he mean by "interpreting" in the statement below, and how is it related to the above?
>
> > i.e, we are interpreting $A_x\cap A_y$ in $A_{xy}$ (or in $k(x,y)$)

Since $X$ is integral, all restriction maps are injective and given any inclusion of open subsets $W\subset U$ we may identify $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ with it's image in $\mathcal{O}_X(W)$. Therefore if we want to ask whether $f_1|_{D(xy)}=f_2|_{D(xy)}$, we can just ask whether (the images of) $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the same element in $\mathcal{O}_X(D(xy))=A_{xy}$. To find all possible pairs of $f_1$ and $f_2$ which satisfy the desired property, we can take the intersection of $\mathcal{O}_X(D(x))=A_x$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(D(y))=A_y$ inside $\mathcal{O}_X(D(xy))=A_{xy}$.

> Next, he writes:
>
> > Clearly those rational functions
> > with only powers of $x$ in the denominator, and also with only powers of y in the
> > denominator, are the polynomials. Translation: $A_x\cap A_y=A$
>
> At this point I've completely lost the discussion thread. I guess this is related to my previous confusion. Why do we need/want to consider $A_x\cap A_y$? How are $D(x), D(y), D(x)\cap D(y)$ related to this?

I've explained why we want to consider $A_x\cap A_y$ above. (In case it's still not clear what $A_x$ has to do with $D(x)$, recall that by the construction of the structure sheaf, $\mathcal{O}_X(D(x))=A_x$ and similarly for $\mathcal{O}_X(D(y))=A_y$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(D(x)\cap D(y))=\mathcal{O}_X(D(xy))=A_{xy}$.)

> What are the $f_1$ and $f_2$ that we wanted to find? Have we found them? And suppose that we've found them. Then the gluability axiom tells us that there is $f\in \mathscr O_{\mathbb A^2}(U)$ such that $Res_{U,U_i} f= f_i$. How does this imply the last claim quoted below?
>
> > Thus we conclude $\Gamma(U, \mathscr O_{\mathbb A^2} )\equiv k[x,y]$

From the computation that $A_x\cap A_y=A$, we know that the only possible pairs of $f_1,f_2$ which restrict as required are those where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are already the same element of $A$. By the first unquoted paragraph above, this implies the result.

Comment: When saying "sections of $\mathscr O_X$ over $D(x)\cup D(y)$ are exactly the choice of an $f_1$ ... and $f_2$...", do you mean that every such section can be constructed by the gluability axiom from a pair $(f_1, f_2)$, and so to describe those sections it's enough to describe the pairs $(f_1, f_2)$? And after we know that such $f_1$ and $f_2$ must be the same polynomial, and after we apply the gluability axiom to get $f$, the fact that $f$ must be a polynomial follows from $Res_{D(x),D(xy)} f=Res_{D(y), D(xy)} f$ since (just like with $f_1$ and $f_2$) $f$ must lie in $A_x\cap A_y=A$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I started to write down this argument, and got confused again. The last equality in my comment is wrong, it should be $Res_{U, D(x)} f=f_1=f_2= Res_{U, D(y)} f$. But how can we use this to show that $f\in A$ if we don't even know yet what the $\mathscr O_X(U)$ is? (So we don't even know the domain of the map $Res_{U, D(x)}$)

Comment: I don't understand what you're complaining about. We showed that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is the intersection of $A_x$ and $A_y$ in $A_{xy}$ and then computed that intersection and found it was $A$.

Comment: Then did I misunderstand the proof? We assumed that (1) $Res_{D(x),D(xy)} f_1=Res_{D(x),D(xy)} f_2$ and proved that (2) $f_1$ and $f_2$ lie in $A$ and are equal. By the gluability axiom, using only (1), we know that there is an $f\in \mathscr O_X(U)$ with the property from my last comment. Now I thought we need to use (2) and the property in my last comment to prove that $f$ itself lies in $A$.

Comment: Yes, we assumed (1) and proved (2). Since we identified everything with it's image in $A_{xy}$ after restriction, this already proves that $f\in A$.

Comment: I don't understand how this proves that $f\in A$. Did we use the conditions $Res_{U,D(x)} f=f_1, Res_{U,D(y)} f=f_2$ at all (which are the conditions from the gluability axiom)? And I think you may be using that $\mathscr O_X(U)=A_{xy}$ or something like that. If so, then I don't understand why this is the case -- for an arbitrary open set $U$, we only know that $\mathscr O_X(U)$ is the set of tuples of compatible germs, but we (or at least I) don't know what $\mathscr O_X(U)$ is in terms of localization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129782/discussion-between-kreiser-and-user634426).